# c++ define a group of const struct in head file

Tags: c++, struct

I am using a C++ library which defines a struct.

Eg.

```
struct demo{
    string x;
    string y;
    string z;
    int n;
};
```

Normally I use this struct this way

```
demo s;
s.x = "AAA";
s.y = "BBB";
```

If I need to use certain values of the struct frequently. It makes sense to define a group of const struct in a new head file. What the right way to define the head file and implementation file(is it needed)? Further more, is there any convenient way to do this by #define preprocessor directives?

```
const struct AAABBB;
const struct AAACCC;
...
const struct BBBCCC;
```

in which x=AAA, y=BBB respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question:

> What the right way to define the head file and implementation file(is it needed)?

You can create a header file that has:

ConstStructs.h:

```
// I assume you meant to use demo and not struct.
extern const demo AAABBB;
extern const demo AAACCC;
...
extern const demo BBBCCC;
```

You can create an implementation file that has:

ConstStructs.cpp:

```
const demo AAABBB = {"AAA", "BBB", "...", N1}; // Use suitable values for z and n
const demo AAACCC = {"AAA", "CCC", "...", N2};
...
const demo BBBCCC = {"BBB", "CCC", "...", N3};
```

I wouldn't worry about using a macro to generate these objects. It's not worth the effort considering that your objects will be a little obfuscated.

**An Alternative**

I am biased against use of global data, const or otherwise. I would much rather provide access to such data through a functional interface.

ConstStructs.h:

```
extern const demo& getAAABBB();
extern const demo& getAAACCC();
...
extern const demo& getBBBCCC();
```

ConstStructs.cpp:

```
const demo& getAAABBB()
{
   static const demo obj = {"AAA", "BBB", "...", N1};
   return obj;
}

const demo& getAAACCC()
{
   static const demo obj = {"AAA", "CCC", "...", N2};
   return obj;
}
...
const demo& getBBBCCC()
{
   static const demo obj = {"BBB", "CCC", "...", N3};
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! what if the number of members in this struct is big, and i only have to initialize a few of them. what the right way to initialize such const struct objects?

Comment: @atsCoder, I would recommend the functional approach. Having to fill out the data for a large number of objects may seem like a painful thing to do but I can assure you that the time you spend on them will be a fraction of the time you spend in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define mydemo(x, y) const struct demo x##y = { #x, #y }
```

Comment: thank you, what if #x #y is the 10th, 14th member in the struct? how do I construct it? assume all others use default values.

Comment: `#x` means make a string consisting of "x", that is `const struct demo AB = {"A", "B"};`